# elevateZoom scrollZoom is not working in Firefox and IE?

Tags: jquery, elevatezoom

Actually, am using elevateZoom jquery plugin for my angular project in that I have used scrollzooom.
The problem is scrollzooom working fine in the Chrome, But it's not working in the firefox and IE.

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us more about your findings, issue and what you've tried out so far?

Comment: I want to like the following example am using http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples  in this Mousewheel Zoom option you'll find. actually it's working fine in chrome only firefox am unable to get

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error in console?

Comment: No nothing am getting